# Process Monitor not showing stack for network events

Tags: windows-xp, process-monitor

I'm trying to trace down some network activity from a process, running under Windows XP.

I see the network events in question, but when I go to look at the stack for that even (on the Stack tab), it is empty.

Other types of events (even for the process in question) *do* show a stack trace, but for network events, it does not.

Is this a known limitation of Process Monitor (or just on Windows XP), or am I missing something?

I'm using the latest version of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), v3.10.

Comment: Did you try the latest version before you asked?  What happened when you did?

Comment: @barlop Yep, I'm on the latest. Forgot to include that, thanks.

Comment: interesting 'cos when I just tried the latest version on XP I got a BSOD. So on XP I have v2.04, I see some differences but I can't quite put my finger on what they are 'cos one comp is upstairs and one downstairs.. would be easier if the screens were side by side.  Also there's tools..network summary. And then there's tools...stack summary. And there's what happens when you double click or click and say 'go to event'. On XP pmon 2.04 neither is empty. As for what thappens when you dblclick or click 'go to event' that's more finnicky.

Answer (score 0):

For 32 bit processes,  I think drstrace, part of drmemory, can do stack traces.